# Issue with inheritance and generic AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, generics, android-asynctask

I wanted to create a class that will execute multiple tasks (generated by a factory) concurrently on a `ThreadExceutor`. However, I am experiencing issues with generics that this class uses.

There are three classes/interfaces involved in this:

1. `ConcurrentAsyncTask`, an abstract class that manages the synchronization and merging of results from multiple executions of the task. It is generic in its arguments and return value. All tasks executed concurrently extend it.
2. `TaskFactory` is a generic interface that creates tasks to be executed concurrently. This is simply used to create multiple instances of the task so that they can be run in parallel.
3. `TestTaskAsync`, an example parallel task that extends `ConcurrentAsyncTask`.

My `ConcurrentAsyncTask` is

```
public abstract class ConcurrentAsyncTask<Params, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Void, List<Result>> {
    ...

    public static <P, R> void executeConcurrent(TaskFactory<P, R> factory, TaskCallback<R> callback, P[] params){
        AtomicInteger remainingCounter = new AtomicInteger(params.length);
        List<R> resultList = new Vector<R>();

        for(P param : params){
            ConcurrentAsyncTask<P,R> task = factory.createTask(remainingCounter, resultList, callback);
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, param);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `TaskFactory` is

```
public interface TaskFactory<Params, Result> {
    public ConcurrentAsyncTask<Params, Result> createTask(AtomicInteger remainingCounter, List<Result> resultList, TaskCallback<Result> callback);
}
```

and an extending class `TestTaskAsync`

```
public class TestTaskAsync extends ConcurrentAsyncTask<IMAPFolder, MessageIndex>{
    public MessageIndexerAsync(AtomicInteger remainingCounter, List<MessageIndex> messageIndexes, TaskCallback<MessageIndex> callback) {
        super(remainingCounter, messageIndexes, callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<MessageIndex> doInBackground(IMAPFolder... folders) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[doInBackground] Processing "+folders[0].getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return new Vector<MessageIndex>();
    }
}
```

I am trying to execute the tasks like so

```
ConcurrentAsyncTask.<IMAPFolder, MessageIndex>executeConcurrent(
    new TaskFactory<IMAPFolder, MessageIndex>() {
        @Override
        public ConcurrentAsyncTask<IMAPFolder, MessageIndex> createTask(AtomicInteger remainingCounter, List<MessageIndex> resultList, TaskCallback<MessageIndex> callback) {
            return new TestTaskAsync(remainingCounter, resultList, callback);
        }
    },
    new TaskCallback<MessageIndex>(){
        @Override
        public void exec(List<MessageIndex> messageIndexes) {

        }
    },
    imapFolders.toArray(new IMAPFolder[imapFolders.size()])
);
```

I am getting an uncaught exception after this. After adding an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` I found out that the issue is in the type `AsyncTask` is receiving as `Params`

```
12-10 17:58:33.272  10774-10818/(...) E/ConcurrentAsyncTask﹕ 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder[]
            at (...).TestTaskAsync.doInBackground(TestTaskAsync.java:19)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

There are two solutions I have found so far

1. Changing the prototype of `TestTaskAsync` to `public class TestTaskAsync extends ConcurrentAsyncTask<Object, MessageIndex>`. Using this approach I verified that the `Object` passed to my `doInBackground` is indeed an instance of `IMAPFolder`. This is not really a preferred method.
2. Changing the prototype of `TestTaskAsync` to `public class TestTaskAsync<T> extends ConcurrentAsyncTask<T, MessageIndex>` and creating instance by `return new TestTaskAsync<IMAPFolder>(remainingCounter, resultList, callback);` - again not useful. 
   Going further with the second approach, I tried `TestTaskAsync<T extends IMAPFolder>`, however that resulted in the same issue as before.

I'm compiling my code using `gradle` for `API15`. What am I missing?

**PS** Android Studio is telling me that the line `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, param);` has `Unchecked generics array creation for vararg parameter`- I'm guessing this has something to do with it, however I do not quite understand what it implies in this context.

**EDIT** Checking `ActualTypeArguments` of `factory.createTask(remainingCounter, resultList, callback)` gives correct values of `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder` and `com.philips.motiva.mail.MessageIndex`

Comment: change `ConcurrentAsyncTask.<IMAPFolder, MessageIndex>executeConcurrent` to `ConcurrentAsyncTask<IMAPFolder, MessageIndex>.executeConcurrent`

Comment: Doesn't compile (`error: not a statement`). Those parameters refer to generic arguments of static method `executeConcurrent` not of the `ConcurrentAsyncTask` :(

Comment: Also, those can completely omitted (`Explicity type arguments can be inferred`). I left them in for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of creation your array params: Object[], your application does not know nothing about the type you will pass, cause you generic type P[] is the same as you will write Object[]. So in the moment when you call executeOnExecutor, your method passes the Object[] array, not only the reference Object[]. As you know, you can't cast Object[] to ChildOfObject[]. You should override also your method executeOnExecutor with params of type IMAPFolder... and then it should work.

But if you write task.execute(), you'll also have the same exception, cause your execute method also has parameters of type Object[], not your custom generics. It is not good practice, to override methods with child type of params. For you it will be better to write next:

```
 @Override
protected List<MessageIndex> doInBackground(Object... folders) {
  if (folder[0] instanceof IMAPFolder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "[doInBackground] Processing "+((IMAPFolder)folders[0]).getClass().getCanonicalName());
    return new Vector<MessageIndex>();
  } else {
   return null;
  }
}
```